# Serializing a tree in Django

Tags: django, serialization, tree

is there any simple way to serialize a tree given by a model such as the Category shown below?

I'd like to get a json object like:

```
[ { 'name': 'cat1',
    'children': [ { 'name': 'cat11',
                    'children': [ ... ]
                ]
  }
  ...
]
```

Thanks

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    order_key = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['order_key']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.name)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll have to walk the tree, and build an object which you serialize using JSON.  I'm assuming your tree is acyclic, because otherwise it gets more complicated.  I haven't tested this, but something like this will work (as long as you're sure you don't have cycles):

```
def serialize_to_json(self):
    return json.dumps(self.serializable_object())

def serializable_object(self):
    "Recurse into tree to build a serializable object"
    obj = {'name': self.name, 'children': []}
    for child in self.get_children():
        obj['children'].append(child.serializable_object())
    return obj
```

(Can't remember if `children_set` is the right way to get the list of children.  Please comment if this is wrong.)

Comment: Thanks. Works with dump instead of dumps and get_children() instead of children_set.all().

Comment: Any reason not to turn that puppy into a list comprehension?

Comment: Readability, that would be one long line of hard to read code ?

Comment: I see you are using `django-mptt`. Make sure you call `cache_tree_children()` before you evaluate your queryset. Otherwise it will hit the database every time you use `get_children()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Tasypie or Django-Piston can help? If not you can have a look at their source code to get some hints on how to do this.