# How can I recursively extract a hierarchical dictionary using a django template?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, recursion, django-templates

I have hierarchical structure:

```
{
    "content": "Header 1", 
    "name": "folder/name.txt", 
    "decendent": [
         {
            "content": "Header 2", 
            "name": "folder/subfolder/name.txt", 
            "decendent": null
        }, 
        {
            "content": "Header 3", 
            "name": "folder/subfolder2/name.txt", 
            "decendent": [
                {
                    "content": "Header 4", 
                    "name": "folder/subfolder2/subsubfolder1/name.txt", 
                    "decendent": null
                }
                ... etc.
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to unroll it using (as an example) this template:

```
                {% for key, value in list.items %}
                <ul class="Container">
                    <li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                        <div class="Expand">

                        </div>


                        <div class="Content">
                            <a href="/help/pur/">
                                {{ key }}
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        {% for k, v in value.items %}
                        <ul class="Container">
                            <li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                                <div class="Expand">

                                </div>

                                <div class="Content">
                                    <a href="/help/test/">
                                        {{ k }}
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                {% for k1, v1 in v.items %}
                                <ul class="Container">
                                        <li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                                            <div class="Expand">

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="Content">
                                                <a href="/help/test/">
                                                    {{ k1 }}
                                                </a>
                                            </div>

                                            {% for k2, v2 in v1.items %}
                                                    <ul class="Container">
                                                        <li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                                                            <div class="Expand">

                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="Content">
                                                                <a href="#" onclick="k2 = '{{ k2 }}'; changeText(k2)">
                                                                    {{ k2 }}
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </li>
                                </ul>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {% endfor %}
```

I have to put the "name" attribute to "a href" tag, and between opening and closing tag extract the "content", for descendents of node I'd like to go through them recursively. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to perform it using django template language considering it's limitations.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32044/3001761? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19193289/3001761?

Comment: Yes, and I don't have a full understanding how to iterate through this structure, because it's a mixture of list and dictionaries inside. I have an intuitive feeling that in my case recursion is only choice but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django can use recursive templates. If you create a template called (for example) `recurse.html`, and pass it a `data` variable with your top-level dictionary:

```
<ul class="Container">
    <li class="Node ExpandClosed">

        <div class="Expand"></div>

        <div class="Content">
            <a href="{{data.name}}">
                {{data.content}}
            </a>
        </div>

        {% for item in data.decendent %}
            {% include 'recurse.html' with data=item %}
        {% endfor %}

    </li>
</ul>
```

That should display for the first level, then re-call itself each time for it's `decendents` with `data` re-bound to the new sub-tree.

Comment: And this code snippet is related to recurse.html or it is located in main.html?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather create a new tag for Jinja2-templates.
[Django-doc reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)